# Is there a problem if I place my tent near a Need Zone?

Tags: the-hunter-call-of-the-wild

Will it cause the animals not spawn or go to the need zones if I place my tent like 70 meters away from a need zone?

If there is a minimal distance to not interfere with the need zone, how many meters should I place the tent?